# Fit html page text to the window width

Tags: android, html, css, webview

Hi I have my website designed for a mobile devices.

I use WebView in my application to show this website.

When the user zooms the text, I get the horizontal scroll bar. Instead, what I want is that, the text in the page, should wrap to the next line and text should fit the screen width.

What html5, css3 properties should be used to wrap the text to fit in the screen of the mobile?

Comment: some code would be nice

Answer (score 2):

on the apple site it says

> The user can also zoom in and out using gestures. When zooming in and
>   out, the user changes the scale of the viewport, not the size of the
>   viewport. Consequently, panning and zooming do not change the layout
>   of the webpage. Figure 3-8 shows the same webpage when the user zooms
>   in to see details.

so I would think it's not something that will be possible, unless you can manipulate the scale

Comment: Is it possible to do something with html5 and css, to make it device/platform independent?

Comment: I think the zoom function is going to work the same no matter what platform, i use android and i don't recall seeing any websites that scale in the same way as with a desktop browser on zoom, you can disable zoom altogether so then you could maybe use one of the javascript mobile phone gesture libraries to program the pinch gesture to change the css to scale the size of everything, that would work i think

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to implement a WebViewClient and to override the OnScaleChanged method, which informs you that the user zoomed in. In this method you need to re-layout the whole WebView. The following code is how I achieved the text reflow (NOTE: If you don't want the scroll bars to show you will need some more code but I haven't added that):

```
WebView view;
view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {

        view.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(
                LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS); //causes the text to reflow to the screen size
        view.invalidate();
        super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
    }
});
```